# os.path.dirname no me da la dirección correcta cuándo lo vuelvo .exe

Tags: python

```
trabajo= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    shutil.move(trabajo+"\\wal.exe",Incio)
```

Cuándo esta sin compilar esto funciona, pero cuándo lo convierto a .exe sale la siguiente dirección.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
  File "prueba.py", line 31, in wal
  File "shutil.py", line 833, in move
  File "shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
  File "shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\cuent\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI160762\\wal.exe'
```

Alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando creas un `EXE` lo que se esta haciendo en realidad es crear un archivo que empaqueta el interprete de `python` y todo tu proyecto, luego, cuando lo ejecutas, lo primero que se hace es  descomprimir todo en una carpeta temporal y luego recién desde esta carpeta, efectivamente se ejecuta tu proyecto. Esto hace que la carpeta inicial no sea aquella dónde se aloja tu `EXE`, sino la temporal dónde se ha descomprimido.

Es decir, `os.path.realpath(__file__)` funciona perfectamente, simplemente la carpeta de inicio no es la que estas asumiendo.

Si estás usando `pyinstaller`, puedes hacer algo asi:

```
# determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    trabajo = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    trabajo = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Esto debería contemplar los dos escenarios, ejecución directa desde el código fuente, y ejecución desde el `EXE` generado.

Cualquier cosa, revisa la [documentación](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/runtime-information.html) de `pyinstaller`.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono perfectamente